# How to disable the feature of split screen in nougat in android through programatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat, split-screen-multitasking

I am making an app. i don't want to my app split in screen as mention in the nougat version. Can anybody tell me how can i do this that my app does not split into screen.

Comment: Then what is it that you makes love Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you manifest add this in the application tag, so it will look like this:

```
<application
android:resizeableActivity="false" >
... 
</application>
```

Comment: Note that this is not reliable. Whether your activity allows resizing does not matter; what matters is whether *the root activity of the task* allows resizing. Various apps on the Play Store will start your app as a resizeable one whether you like it or not, by putting you in their own task, as I describe [in this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/12/multi-window-multi-instance-like-it-or-not.html). Also, [a developer option in Settings](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/20/multi-window-like-it-or-not-again.html) may override this.

Answer (score 1):

in mainfest

```
android:resizeableActivity="false"
```

if you want to disable particular Acticity or screen

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:resizeableActivity="false" />
```

or if you want to disable it in your entire app

```
<application 
   android:resizeableActivity="false" >
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

you need set targetSdkVersion  = 24 or higher. otherwise it will not working.

Comment: Always prefer to add some explanation with the tag, that why it will not work with `targetSdkVersion = 24 or higher`.

Comment: sorry, i also just tried many times, then find this working.  i  will reply here if i get any update